# Read CSV file with Scanner

Tags: java

I have CSV file with this example line
1;name;region;district;210055;1709
2;name;string;district;13924;1942

How can I read a file with a scanner between ; and without reading the first digit.
But i get exception NoSuchElementException

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get("src/main/resources/city.csv");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(path);
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        City city = parseInfo(scanner.next());
        System.out.println(city);
    }
    scanner.close();
}

private static City parseInfo(String line) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
    scanner.useDelimiter("\\s*,\\s*");
    String name = scanner.next();
    String region = scanner.next();
    String district = scanner.next();
    int population = scanner.nextInt();
    int foundation = scanner.nextInt();
    return new City(name, region, district, population, foundation);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the question only, for education's sake...

First, if you want to skip the first field, simply do `scanner.nextInt()` without assigning it to anything. `scanner` here is essentially a cursor.

Second, if your delimiter is a semicolon (";"), then you need to specify that in the `scanner.useDelimiter()` which you're current setting to a comma (",").

```
private static City parseInfo(String line) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
    scanner.useDelimiter("\\s*;\\s*");
    scanner.nextInt();
    String name = scanner.next();
    String region = scanner.next();
    String district = scanner.next();
    int population = scanner.nextInt();
    int foundation = scanner.nextInt();
    return new City(name, region, district, population, foundation);
}
```